# Dynamic naming of variable inside for loop

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to create 16 `Textbox`es, named `textbox1` to `textbox16`, inside a for loop which runs for 16 times. Hence, 1 `textbox` is created in each loop. How to achieve this ?

Comment: Why do you want to change the name of the variable in each iteration? Don't you want to change the `Name` of the `TextBox` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make dynamically named variables. In this kind of situationen, it makes most sense to keep the controls in some collection, for instance in a `List<T>`:

```
List<TextBox> textBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
for(int i = 1 ; i <= 16 ; i++ )
{
    var tb = new TextBox() { Name = "textbox" + i };
    textBoxes.Add(tb);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for(int counter=0;counter<16;counter++){
    TextBox TB = new TextBox();
    TB.Id = "textbox" + (counter + 1);

    // code to add this textbox in screen

}
```

Comment: how will i access individual textbox ?

Comment: You will create any kind of placeholder in the screen and add these textboxes into it. You can find these controls via FindControl Method.